# jquery number spinner not working with float numbers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, numbers

I have this JQUERY nice number spinner, but it's not stepping in floats when I give write to go by .01 digits at a time.
here is the code:
jquery in the head:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.nice-number.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
  <script src="js/jquery.nice-number.js"></script>
```

the input and the nice number script:

```
<input type="number" value="1.0" name="qty" step="0.1" max="99999" min="0.1">
    <script>

        $(function () {

            $('input[type="number"]').niceNumber();

        });

    </script>
```

how can I solve?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a source for your `jquery.nice-number.js`?  Preferably a working CDN.    Is it relevant to your question or does it do the same without?  (Edit: seems to work ok without it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Assuming this is from: https://github.com/joshua-s/jquery.nice-number

A quick look at the source shows:

```
var newValue = currentValue + 1;
```

so the nice-number plugin is *hardcoded* to only add/subtract +1/-1

It does provide a callback, so you *could* edit the value, but might be better to edit the nice-number.js to pass in the increment step via settings.

```js
$(function() {

  $('input[type="number"]').niceNumber({
    onDecrement: ($el, newValue, settings) => {
      $el.val(Math.round((newValue + 0.9) * 100) / 100);
      console.log($el.val())
    },
    onIncrement: ($el, newValue, settings) => {
      //console.log($el.val())
      $el.val(Math.round((newValue - 0.9) * 100) / 100);
      console.log($el.val())
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.nice-number.css">-->
<link ref="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.nice-number@2.1.0/dist/jquery.nice-number.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--<script src="js/jquery.nice-number.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.nice-number@2.1.0/dist/jquery.nice-number.js"></script>


<input type="number" value="1.0" name="qty" step="0.1" max="99999" min="0.1" style='width:200px;'>
```

Comment: is there a way where I use both the first type where the step is by 1 digit at a time and 0.1 digit. maybe targeting input with certain class?

Comment: You could call .niceNumber separately for each input / group of input types.   `$(".niceNumberInt").niceNumber(); $(".niceNumber1dp").niceNumber({onIncrement...`